# Delete operator behavior on non existing indexed element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does delete operator return true if I try to delete non existing indexed element of an array?

More precisely deletion of undefined is true in javascript?

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d'];

console.log(delete arr[2000]);  //true why?

console.log(delete aaaaa);     //true  why not reference error?

console.log(delete arrr[2000]);  //reference error  it's okay i think
```

I don't understand difference between 2nd and 3rd deletion. Both should ideally give reference error.

Comment: because it worked, arr[2000] is not there anymore.

Comment: do u mean deletion of undefined is true? arr[2000] was undefined

Comment: The real question is what are you trying to do, this might be a classical XY Problem case.

Comment: updated my answer to your edits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Returns false only if the property exists and cannot be deleted. It
>   returns true in all other cases.

edit:

here you just delete a in your scope, mostly the window scope

```
console.log(delete aaaaa);     //true  why not reference error?
```

so its the same as:

```
console.log(delete window.aaaaa);     //true
```

here arrr is undefined and you get an reference error before the delete method is called

```
console.log(delete arrr[2000]);  //reference error  it's okay i think
```